# Orchard CMS: RemoteRss from Vandelay Industries

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I'm stumbling my way around Orchard CMS and want to override the default template for the RemoteRSS widget from Vandelay Industries. The current template is located at:

```
~/Modules/Vandelay.Industries/Views/Parts/RemoteRss.cshtml
```

So,

- Is it possible to override this template
- If so, where do I place my new template, so as to not 'damage' the original

I've tried saving it as:

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\cc_orchard_live_2012\Themes\FlexoPurchased\Views\RemoteRss.cshtml

C:\inetpub\wwwroot\cc_orchard_live_2012\Themes\FlexoPurchased\Views\Parts.RemoteRss.cshtml

C:\inetpub\wwwroot\cc_orchard_live_2012\Themes\FlexoPurchased\Views\Parts\RemoteRss.cshtml
```

but these either seem to not take effect or even cause an error.

---

### Additional Info

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\cc_orchard_live_2012\Themes\FlexoPurchased\Views\RemoteRss.cs‌​html
```

Doesn't appear to have any effect.

```
~/Modules/Vandelay.Industries/Views/Parts/RemoteRss.cshtml
```

Same code here works fine however.

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\cc_orchard_live_2012\Themes\FlexoPurchased\Views\Parts.Remote‌​‌​Rss.cshtml
```

causes a runtime error:

> Compiler Error Message: CS0012: The type 'System.Xml.IXmlLineInfo' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\cc_orchard_live_2012\Themes\FlexoPurchased\Views\Parts\Remote‌​‌​Rss.cshtml
```

throws a runtime error:

> Compiler Error Message: CS0012: The type 'System.Xml.IXmlLineInfo' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

Comment: you mean with the cshtml extension? It's missing up there.

Comment: Also, what error are you seeing?

Comment: @Betrand Le Roy, please see my op as Ive now updated this with the various errors / results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reference System.Xml from your theme's project in order to be able to override that template.

Comment: HOW to do it would be useful in an answer.

Comment: o_O Right click "references" under the theme's project, choose "add reference", check System.Xml.

Comment: Put that in your answer. Ideally, you'd also want to explain how you would add a reference without the aid of Visual Studio.

Comment: The question was not about how to add a reference to a project.

Answer (score 0):

You can overcome this problem by copying System.Xml.dll into your site's /bin folder. No further configuration is needed.

If you don't know where to find this file, create a new web project, add a reference to System.Xml to your project, right click on the new reference in the references list, go to the Copy Local property and change it to true. When you build the project, System.Xml.dll will be copied to your project's /bin directory. You can get it from there.

Comment: I think this should be a comment rather than an answer to be honest. Bertrand, answered the question some time ago. Whilst I really appreciate you taking the time to add additional info, it's not really a new answer in itself.

Comment: Your input has been noted. Thanks.